# How to configure call detail record (CDR) path asterisk?

Tags: sqlite, asterisk, cdr

I am working with Asterisk. I config Asterisk auto write CDR to SQLite3 and the file is Master.db

By default, this file location in "var/log/asterisk/Master.db".

But now I want to change this path, I want Asterisk auto write CDR to another directory.

How can I change this path?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
currently, only file "master.db" is supported, with only one table at a time.
```

You always can change it it source files and recompile.

Or just create symlink.

Comment: I know, I don't want to change file "master.db" but I want to change directory to story it. Can you help me?

Comment: Simple way - do symlink to other directory. More complex way - change in source code and recompile